# Duda al ázar un entero usando println()

Tags: java

tengo una duda y aunque he buscado el porqué en internet, sin embargo no he encuntrado respuesta.

por qué si inicializo un entero antecediendo por cero, y lo imprimo, coloca un número distinto a la hora de compilar.

```
nt a = 012;
System.out.println(a);
```

salida

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `012` es notación [octal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal), por eso sale un número diferente. `1 * 8 + 2 * 8 = 10`, por eso sale `10`

Comment: @Benjamín: Dirás `1*(8^1) + 2*(8^0) = 1*8 + 2*1 = 8 + 2 = 10`

Comment: @Sal correcto. Gracias por la observación.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En una variable tipo `int` puedes almacenar un valor octal entero, esto lo realizas agregando un 0 como prefijo seguido de la representaciòn octal (ùnicamente numeros del 0 - 7).

```
int a = 012;
System.out.println(a);
```

por esta razòn la salida serìa el numero decimal:

```
10
```

---

Este es el calculo que se realiza:

```
12 = (1 × 8¹) + (2 × 8⁰) = 10
```